# Do I really need the App_Start contents in Ninject.MVC3?

Tags: .net, ninject

Downloading the Ninject.MVC3 package from NuGet creates this App_Start folder with a simple class in it; Which doesn't even compile out of the box, I might add.

Browsing through it, it doesn't seem to have any spectacular... functionality... or any at all. I also do not find it in the `SampleApplication` for `Ninject.Web.Mvc` where the project itself comes from. (https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/tree/master/mvc3/src/SampleApplication)

Can someone explain the purpose of this folder/class? Deleting them seems to have no effect on my project. Is there some mystical ninja reason why I need to keep them? (or even why they are being made in the first place?)

Comment: The lastest version of Ninject.MVC3?  I don't get this folder, but I do get an AppStart_NinjectMVC3.cs file/class that's critical for setting up Ninject.

Comment: Yeah, this is the latest version. I pulled it just 3 minutes ago in a test project before posting this. I get a folder `App_Start` with a file `NinjectMVC3.cs` that has some methods (that don't work) in it. I can't figure out why I would want these. I can't even find where they are called from in the logic tree.

Comment: @Ciel - VS2010/.NET 4/MVC3 project?

Comment: Yes. I clicked on Visual Studio 2010 (SP1), Clicked on "Create Project", Clicked on "ASP.NET MVC 3 Application", took the defaults with a Razor view engine, opened the nuGet Console and typed `install-package Ninject.MVC3' and hit Enter, and it all appeared.

Comment: @Ciel -- that might explain it.  I'm using the right-click, Add Library Reference dialog to add Ninject.MVC3.  I just tried it in a fresh (empty) project and got the results I included in my answer.

Comment: @Ciel - my bad, I was using a slightly older version (from the Recently Used menu).  The slightly newer version does create the folder and a single file.  It is necessary -- see my updated answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Updated documentation: https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/wiki/Setting-up-an-MVC3-application

Comment: Thanks, Remo. So basically they're two different ways to do the same thing, and I can just do whichever I feel comfortable with?

Comment: @Ciel - @Remo's comment's not withstanding, I'd follow the NuGet way if you are installing from the package manager. When I upgraded to the latest NuGet version (from my slightly older version), it changed things around to the current configuration. I'd hate for you to delete the file, then have your package updates fail.

Comment: Reading Remo's description, the App_Start method was only introduced to automate integration from the NuGet installer, and not as the inherit manner of wiring. I can infer from this that, unless his stance with development changes, there is no intention to break the typical convention in favor of the automated convention. Though I could be wrong, just the way I guess. Thanks again, Remo!

Comment: @tvanfosson: You're correct that this would be more convenient, but truthfully doing the wiring myself teaches me more than letting the package manager do it. I view the package manager as more of a simple download repository, not an implementation tool. I understand, and completely agree, with this WebActivator approach, but that's just not the way I learn how something works.

Comment: There is no internsion not to drop support for either way. But I if installing from NuGet the NuGet way is far more comfortable. It allows installation of multiple packages that would need to derive from HttpApplication. And the dependencies (e.g. WebActivator) will be installed on every update.

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of Ninject.MVC3 creates a folder, named App_Start, in your project.  This folder contains the NinjectMVC3.cs class, which is the bootstrapper code for the Ninject framework.  It has two assembly attributes that are used to start and stop the NinjectMVC3 code.  It is these attributes that cause the WebActivator framework to invoke the bootstrapper class methods and start up the Ninject framework.  Installing NinjectMVC3 also adds assembly references for Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure, Ninject, NinjectMVC3, and WebActivator.

The NinjectMVC3 class contains the RegisterServices method where you would add code to bind your interfaces to their concrete implementations.  This is the file that you would edit to configure your dependencies.

This required, and is the only requirement, for using Ninject with your MVC application to handle your dependencies.  Other instructions on adding code to global.asax.cs should be ignored.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand. So I have to have everything registered in two locations, now? And I need to be part of this 'WebActivator'? Things have been working fine without it, what do I need it for now?

Comment: https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/wiki/Setting-up-an-MVC3-application doesn't really make it clear whether the `NinjectMVC3.cs` file is _required_, it just says it's made when you get the package by NuGet. I have my application inheriting from `NinjectHttpApplication`, but I still have to have this `Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll` and `WebActivator.dll` assembly referenced, and I still have to use this `NinjectMVC3.cs` file regardless?

Comment: @Ciel - if you're following the instructions to inherit from NinjectHttpApplicationModule and add code to global.asax.cs, those are old instructions and can be disregarded AFAIK.

Comment: https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/wiki/Setting-up-an-MVC3-application - it's 8 days old...

Answer (score 0):

Same question here gives the short answer = "No". It's just a new convention which only makes sense for large web sites and even that is not sure.

http://weblogs.asp.net/pjohnson/archive/2012/09/07/mvc-4-and-the-app-start-folder.aspx

Personally I prefer to deal with all routing and filter overrides in the global application class, shifting all common stuff to a shared base class so it only contains web site specific code. I see no need for separate classes either.

The usual case with ASP.NET special folders is that they provide different security permissions. Does anyone know if this App_Start folder is necessary in a partial trust environment? i.e. with restricted web hosting, is this the only place where you are allow to call functions to change the way the site routes?

Sounds like somebody at MS is thinking about adding this as a additional layer of security in the future, if it is not already there. Until I see a real world benefit of this I would just delete it.